# Web session in pure python

Tags: python

I am creating a web site using python and html/css. I am not using any web framework just using pure python.
I want to implement session in this site but cant find appropriate code/example for it. Please somebody help me out in this.

If possible can you please send me a code or link.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a `Cookie` module in its stdlib that allows you to create and manipulate cookies in a server written in Python. Writing a HTTP server in Python is easy - just use `BaseHTTPServer` - again from the stdlib. With the `Cookie` module it shouldn't be difficult to implement sessions, since sessions are usually based on cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You want to [write a WSGI app](http://wsgi.org/wsgi/Learn_WSGI).

Answer (score 0):

You *want* to use a web-framework for writing a web-site.
Everything else is un-needed minimalism.