# how to transfer data from onepage to another using python

Tags: python, html

I want to transfer data from one to another pages, like my login detail are display in another page then what can I do

My Python Server code:

```
    from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    import BaseHTTPServer
    from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs


    class CustomHTTPRequestHandler(SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

        def do_POST(self):
            try:
                length = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length'))
                data = self.rfile.read(length)
                self.send_response(200, "OK")
                print data.split('&')
                #process_data(data, self.client_address)
            except Exception as inst:
                logging.error(type(self).__name__ + "/" + type(inst).__name__ + " \
    (" + inst.__str__() + ")")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('\
    ', 8544), CustomHTTPRequestHandler).serve_forever()
```

My Html First file `index.html`

```
<form action="" method="POST">
                        User Name :
                            <input type="text"id="username" name="username" placeholder="Enter User Name">
                        Password  :
                            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" laceholder="Enter Password">
                            <button type="submit" id="submit">Sign in</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

In second HTML file (index2.html) I want to display data which is entered into the `index.html`

For that things I search so many thread but I'm not success to found or some of I'm not understand so please help me what changes are into server or any thing else.

Comment: Do you want to use a web framework? Like flask?

Comment: That information should come from your server, not from the posted data, otherwise the user could spoof the page and have it display incorrect data.

Comment: no i'm no use any types of framework

Comment: using POST method i get the data from form page to server and its stored in `DATA` variable but now transfer server to another page, that is my problem.

Comment: I think that in this case you have to use at least a template engine which will receive data from python it self while loading the new page this way you can use the data posted from the page before. Here you can find some : https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating

Comment: directlly i am not put data into the html file from the server ?

Comment: Basically, it sounds like you need to maintain some state somewhere on the server for each client (session). Read up on cookies and sessions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6327180/web-session-in-pure-python asks about implementing sessions in pure Python. The answers on there suggest using a framework. That's because there's lots of gotchas with web development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of doing this is with cookie based sessions. That is, on the initial request the web server provides the client with a session cookie. That cookie gets stored in the users web browser for the duration of the browsing session.

All subsequent HTTP requests include that session ID (which is basically a random, un-guessable string). The server then uses that session ID to retrieve whatever information is on the server associated with the particular client (e.g. contents of shopping cart).

I suggest you read up about cookies here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie